# Why does `bind`'s returning function have no `prototype` property?

Tags: javascript

```js
let f = Array.bind({a:1})
f.prototype === undefined // true
typeof f === 'function' // true
```

Almost all of JavaScript's functions have a `prototype` property. I'm wondering what happens in `bind`. Did it remove `prototype`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the official JavaScript spec, [ECMAScript 2020](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-function.prototype.bind):

> NOTE 1
> Function objects created using `Function.prototype.bind` are exotic
> objects. They also do not have a `prototype` property.

These so-called ["bound function exotic objects"](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#bound-function-exotic-object) are not regular `Function` objects.